# Not able to save cookies from a website using Python requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

For the link : http://www.ibnlive.com/videos/world/

by using a web browser I can easily see the following cookies when page is loaded as shown :

[image]

But if I try to load the same cookies using python requests, it shows up as an empty dictionary :

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
connection = s.get('http://www.ibnlive.com/videos/world/')
print(s.cookies) # produces an empty dictionary
```

My question how can I get those cookies using a python script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the cookie is not being set by `http://www.ibnlive.com/videos/world/`, but some other resource that the page is loading. Try looking at the headers for that *url*, you won't see any `Set-Cookie` headers.

Comment: Right, but any page on that domain can set a cookie. So it could be `http://www.ibnlive.com/some/cookie/setter/path`, that your browser loads once it loads your URL.

Comment: Is there a generalized solution to this problem ?

Comment: The most generalized way would be to imitate the browser. That is, once you load the main page, parse all the URLs using a regex & then load them using the `Session`. But that will be *slow* & pointless. Presumably you only need the `_vrf` cookie? Just spend the time once to figure out which page is actually setting the cookie, and just load it with the `Session`.

Comment: Although, I should add, the above approach will fail if it's some JavaScript that is doing the loading, i.e. you won't be able to parse the URL. Your best bet is to use tools that actually imitate the browser like, `PhantonJS` or `selenium`.